# Wordpress - How does one make a URL return dynamic JSON with custom Content Type?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, url-rewriting

Some background first, I'm trying to follow the directions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1

to get universal links working with my website for iOS devices. My wordpress site is in a shared hosting environment, therefore I do NOT have access to the server or any root files. I placed the file at the root of my site (httpdocs) and when I navigate to the page it does not load. In googling around, I found a stackoverflow post stating you had to config the server to let it know to serve up that file with a content type of "application/pkcs7-mime" (Config apple-app-site-association file with wordpress). As mentioned I do not have access to that.

I have a subdomain which is a microsoft web api project that I am very familiar with. I made an endpoint for "apple-app-site-association" and dynamically built the json response in code and set the content type and returned it. This ended up working and Apple detects it and everything. This is interesting as I do NOT need a file on my server as I generate it on the fly, and I don't need to change anything server wise.

The issue however is I need the main site domain to be the universal link, not the windows subdomain. The main site is wordpress. I'm thinking if may be possible to do the same thing in wordpress where I navigate to mydomain.com/apple-app-site-association and I generate the json and content-type on the fly and serve it up.

I've never done any coding with wordpress and don't even know where to start.

If possible I would like clear direction in the following:

Making mydomain.com/apple-app-site-association lead to a custom function or page that serves up json.
Have code that makes the json get served up dynamically.
Have code that sets the content-type of the response to "application/pkcs7-mime".
Of course if someone knows how to solve the file not being served no a shared server without this method, I'm open to that as well. From what I can see, this may be the only way assuming this can be done.

Comment: How about [creating a custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)? (there are easy-to-follow guide/examples there) But I'm curious, are you expecting the URL to return a JSON-encoded string, but then the `Content-Type` is `application/pkcs7-mime`?

Comment: But if you're not going to need/use any WordPress functions like `get_posts()`, then you could just rewrite the URL to a PHP file which generates and serve the dynamic content.

Comment: @SallyCJ Everything I read about creating a custom endpoint stated that a namespace was always needed and it appears after wp-json so my domain/wp-json/custom-namespace/customendpoint. I need mydomain.com/apple-app-site-association. For your first comment, yes it would be a JSON encoded string with a different content type being the pkcs7-mime one. Application/json won't be detected by apple. Your second comment sounds like it might be easier, if I have a URL go to a dynamic php file or even a static file, and can change the content type it should work. How would I go about that?

Comment: @mickmackusa Why are you waiting until the bounty is over? Why not do it now? I believe it is specific, how can I get the Apple apple-app-site-association URL to work in a shared Wordpress environment? You'll find when googling that there isn't an available answer to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note: I'm assuming WordPress is installed in the root folder.**

So if you want `http://example.com/apple-app-site-association` to serve a JSON content like [this](https://pastebin.com/vR8jVQB5) and have the content type (`Content-Type` header) set to `application/pkcs7-mime`, here are some options you can choose from:

### Dynamic Content

***Because you're using WordPress, this might be a better option for you than manually editing the `.htaccess` file.***

You can use the `parse_request` hook; this way, you don't need any custom (WordPress) rewrite rules, no need for a custom Page (post type of `page`), and you don't need to create any JSON file.

*And make sure there's no file named `apple-app-site-association` in the root folder, or a WordPress Page having the slug `apple-app-site-association`.*

So this would go in your theme functions file (e.g. `wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`):

```php
<?php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'serve_apple_app_site_association', 0 );
function serve_apple_app_site_association( $wp ) {
    // Check if the request is /apple-app-site-association
    if ( 'apple-app-site-association' !== $wp->request ) {
        return;
    }

    // Array version of the JSON data.
    $data = array(
        'applinks'    => array(
            'apps'    => array(),
            'details' => array(
                array(
                    'appID' => '9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc',
                    'paths' => array(
                        '/wwdc/news/',
                        '/videos/wwdc/2015/*',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'appID' => 'ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc',
                    'paths' => array(
                        '*',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    // Send headers.
    status_header( 200 );
    nocache_headers();
    header( 'Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime' );

    // And serve the JSON data.
    echo wp_json_encode( $data );
    exit;
}
```

### Static Content

1. Place the JSON data in a file named `apple-app-site-association` (i.e. no extension) and save the file in the root folder where you could see the `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess` files.
2. Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files apple-app-site-association>
        Header set Content-Type application/pkcs7-mime
</Files>
```

*If the `<Files>` and/or `Header` don't/doesn't work for you, then you could just use the first option above, but use something like `readfile()` to read the static file.*

Alternatively (and specifically if URL rewriting is not available/supported on your site), you could create a folder named `apple-app-site-association` in the root folder and add `index.php` to that folder and in that file:

```php
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime' );
// Read the static file or just generate a dynamic content.
@readfile( __DIR__ . '/apple-app-site-association.json' );
exit;
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as It turns out that since I had a static file already at the root that was the same name it wasn't working. I couldn't get the static method to work in the web.config file as this is a windows server. The dynamic method did work perfectly though now that I removed the static file and everything is detected by apple etc. Thank you so so much! For anyone reading this, while I didn't use the static method, the method seems sound so it may be easier for some to do it that way. Just make sure the static file isn't there if you are doing the dynamic way.

Comment: I've revised the answer - thanks for noticing the `Content-Type` typo! And also the file conflict. :)

Comment: Just want to say this is one of the most helpful stack overflow answers I have ever seen. There is very little information on the web about this topic, and this answer is clear and thorough.

Comment: @9gt53wS thanks a lot for your support and I'm glad the answer helped you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Was very helpful! In my case I had to change `application/pkcs7-mime` to `application/json` to make it work :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Do you know if the 'parse_request' method still works? It was working on my website and now it doesn't and I tried on a few others and it also doesn't work. I get a 404 now. It's like parse request doesn't get hit if there wasn't content at that URL.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444, yes `parse_request` still works. That's the hook WordPress uses with the REST API. If you continue to get the issue, you can try disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme - and use the code as a [Must Use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/). You can also try flushing the permalinks - just visit the permalink settings page.